# Why is $\sup_{x∈[0,1]} {|p'(x)|} ≤ A_d\sup_{x∈[0,1]}{|p(x)|}$ for all polynomials $p$ of degree at most $d$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials, supremum-and-infimum

How can one prove that for any positive integer $d$, there is a constant $A_d < 0$ such that
$$
\sup_{x∈[0,1]}
{\lvert\, p'(x)\rvert} ≤ A_d\sup_{x∈[0,1]}{\lvert\, p(x)\rvert},
$$
for all polynomials $p$ of degree at most $d$?

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent of saying that the differential operator is continuous, which is clear, since the vector space of polynomials of degree at most $d$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: I'm trying to show with this inequality that polynomials with large
derivatives at some point in $[0, 1]$ must also have large values at some point in $[0, 1]$.  Can you help me make this a bit more explicit in showing this?

Comment: For this to hold you have to make sure that your constant $A_d$ is relatively small since $A_{d}^{-1}sup_{x\in [0,1]}\vert p'(x) \vert \leq sup_{x \in [0,1]} \vert p(x)\vert$

Comment: @Jimm: My answer already showed your claim. What precisely haven't you understood?

Answer (score 0):

Define the functions $f: \mathbb R^{d+1}\to \mathbb R$ and $g: \mathbb R^{d}\to \mathbb R$, as
$$
f(a_0,\ldots,a_d)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\left|\textstyle\sum_{k=0}^d a_kx^k\right|
\quad\text{and}\quad
g(a_1,\ldots,a_d)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\left|\textstyle\sum_{k=0}^{d-1} ka_kx^{k-1}\right|.
$$
It is clear that both $f$ and $g$ are norms in $\mathbb R^{d+1}$ and $\mathbb R^d$, respectively, and hence equivalent to every other norm in those spaces. Thus there exist $c_d,C_d>0$ such that
$$
c_d g(a_1,\ldots,a_d)\le
\|(a_1,\ldots,a_d)\|_{d}\le
\|(a_0,\ldots,a_d)\|_{d+1}\le C_d\, f(a_0,\ldots,a_d),
$$ 
where $\,\|\cdot\|_{d},\,\|\cdot\|_{d+1}\,$ are the standard Euclidean norms in $\mathbb R^d$ and $\mathbb R^{d+1}$, repsectively.
Thus
$$
\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\lvert p'(x)\rvert=g(a_1,\ldots,a_d)\le \frac{C_d}{c_d}f(a_0,\ldots,a_d)=
\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\lvert p(x)\rvert,
$$
whenever $p(x)=a_0+\cdots+a_dx^d$.

Answer (score -1):

To see a proof that makes this inequality precise, stating that $A_d \leq d^2$, look up Markov's inequality.